# Star Trek: Into Darkness — How do Gaila and others like her attend the Academy on Earth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

I thought Orion woman had influence over males of certain species. So, how would male students, teachers, staff and inhabitants of Earth (from all species that were affected by Orion women) be able to function with Orion women around? Wouldn't the women be able to take advantage of men?

I think in the original series with Kirk, he was able to resist the lures of the Orion women because he loved the Enterprise so much.

There is also the issue of a timeline. I think the crew of the Enterprise in the original series discovered the Orion race when they were out in their five-year mission. So, technically, Gaila and other Orions should not even be on Earth during the "Into Darkness" movie.

Now, I enjoy the new version of Star Trek. I was a youngster for the original series. So, I have seen them all on TV and elsewhere. I think the new version does a good job to keep the Star Trek series alive. I hope there are more movies.

I'm just bringing this up for discussion. It is not an argument or a "pointing a finger in disgust" at an error. Like I said: I enjoy the new version very much.

Comment: The answer is "JJ Abrams laughs at your silly continuity questions and sleeps on a mattress filled with hundred dollar bills in his gold-plated mansion".

Comment: This isn't a cannon answer so that's why I am not making it an answer, but isn't the Orion influence derived by pheromones? The Orions could wear an anti-pheromone or pheromone blocker, so could the other students. Having been to boot camp myself, I do know they line you up and give you vaccines for just about anything and everything that's commonly passed around a large population. I imagine there would be a similar process upon entrance to star fleet.

Comment: On a serious note,  in the Star Trek film there was a race whose sexual attraction (to humans) borders on irresistible. They simply have rules and regulations to get around it.

Comment: “I think the crew of the Enterprise discovered the Orion race when they were out in their five-year mission.” — even if so, the appearance of the Narada could have changed events such that the Orions came into contact with the Federation much earlier.

Comment: I don't think the preemptive disclaimer that *this is not a rant* is necessary.   It sort of comes off as a rant about people frowning on rants.

Comment: Lets not forget that the timeline could have been affected a lot earlier than the events of the first movie, if we consider that subsequent major events could have still happened, such as a new timeline version of First Contact, only this time with a different crew etc, resulting in a different mindset after Cochranes first flight.  This also potentially explains why the ships in the JJ-verse are very different to the original timeline.

Comment: I don't recall Kirk ever encountering an Orion female other than Marta in Whom Gods Destory (and she was insane and he didn't really have any trouble dealing with her). Are you sure you aren't thinking of Pike?

Comment: Routine pheromone suppressant shots?

Comment: You are thinking of Elasian women per TOS: "Elaan of Troyius".

Comment: Orci says in an interview that she essentially has to avoid enclosed spaces with men for extended periods. R-rated sitcom hi jinks ensue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is dealt with in the film's [official novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(novel)), the short answer is that she *is* intoxicating to males but they're under strict orders not to get too near to her. Presumably she's also under the same restrictions, albeit this doesn't stop her from seducing Kirk.

> As they followed the progress of the simulation, the test administrators and technicians were careful not to get too close to the tech seated slightly off to the left at the main console. With her bright green skin she was immediately identifiable as an Orion humanoid. **Since it was both visually and chemically unavoidable, admiration of such beings was permitted, so long as the admirer did not linger in the vicinity. It was recognized that extended proximity to an Orion female was distracting to other humanoids. In fact, it could be downright dangerous.**
>
> Anyone who happened to be looking in her direction suddenly found themselves wrenched back to reality.

Comment: Never thought that novelization would deal with this issue too.

Comment: You should read it. It's quite good.

Comment: BTW, did Kirk seduce her or she seduced Kirk? She looked innocent to me...

Comment: Ask it as a question.

Comment: I never read any of the books. I need to check the local library. I know they have some. Thanks for that, Richard.

Comment: I do have one observation and things to share: In the courtroom scene, Gaila is in the audience with a very angry look on her face. I guess the judges and high-ranking officers sitting up front facing her are able to resist.   I also read that Vulcans are immune.    There is also a deleted scene with an Orion on the ship. So, I guess they are also allowed to serve on a starship.